# iOS - change cell background of DSlCalendarView library

Tags: ios, xcode

I integrate [DSLCalendarView Library](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView)  to my application , its work nice but i need use to view my events .

first i need custom cell view  for event , how can i do that from library method

DSLCalendarDayView.m

## pragma mark Drawing

```
- (void)drawBackground {
    if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected) {
        if (self.isInCurrentMonth) {
            [[UIColor colorWithWhite:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
        }
        else {
            [[UIColor colorWithWhite:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
        }
        UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    }
    else {
        switch (self.selectionState) {
            case DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected:
                break;
                
            case DSLCalendarDayViewStartOfSelection:
                [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-left"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
                break;
                
            case DSLCalendarDayViewEndOfSelection:
                [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-right"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
                break;
                
            case DSLCalendarDayViewWithinSelection:
                [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection-middle"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
                break;
                
            case DSLCalendarDayViewWholeSelection:
                [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarDaySelection"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:self.bounds];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```